# Very strange partition table: Missing a sector between Main and Recovery partition

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

So I have been trying to get Windows 7 on my machine using no DVD or USB (I have only an ISO to work with). I used various combinations of Boot Camp, Toast Titanium, Virtualbox / VMWare, Disk Utility, and rEFIt to attempt this, and after realizing that nothing had worked and getting a DVD-RW, I set about putting everything back to normal, i.e:

- Changing my MBR table back to a single EFI protective partition spanning the entire disk (apparently, Boot Camp magically did that for me)
- Making my OS X partition fill my whole disk again (in the EFI table, using Disk Utility).

So now everything looks pretty much fine from the outside, but there's on detail that bothers me a little bit. Here's the output from `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s4
```

As you can see, I have no `disk0s3` partition. My Recovery HD partition should be in `disk0s3` and I should have no `disk0s4`. But I have no idea how this came about or how severe it is, and only the faintest idea how to fix it (deleting, making a new Recovery HD, not sure if that'll work)

As well, here is the output from rEFIt's Partition Inspector:

```
*** Report for internal hard disk ***

Current GPT partition table:
 #      Start LBA      End LBA  Type
 1             40       409639  EFI System (FAT)
 2         409640    975503591  Mac OS X HFS+
 3      975503592    976773127  Mac OS X Boot

Current MBR partition table:
 # A    Start LBA      End LBA  Type
 1              1    976773167  ee  EFI Protective

MBR contents:
 Boot Code: Unknown, but bootable

Partition at LBA 40:
 Boot Code: None (Non-system disk message)
 File System: FAT32
 Listed in GPT as partition 1, type EFI System (FAT)

Partition at LBA 409640:
 Boot Code: None
 File System: HFS Extended (HFS+)
 Listed in GPT as partition 2, type Mac OS X HFS+

Partition at LBA 975503592:
 Boot Code: None
 File System: HFS Extended (HFS+)
 Listed in GPT as partition 3, type Mac OS X Boot
```

Which confirms that my MBR table is in the right place, and also tells me that my `disk0s2` and `disk0s4` are indeed right next to each other, so there is no invisible partition in between.

Thanks for your help!

Matt

Comment: Did your disk check show bad sector 3 ?

Comment: disk utility doesn't say anything is wrong. anything else i should run?

Answer (score -1):

Rebooting the system reorganized the list on my mac

Comment: It would be useful if you could elaborate on the issue you had (in relation to this question) and what changed in your system after the reboot.